# How to send the mobile version of a webpage?

Tags: webpage, mobile-url

I often share links with my friends from my mobile phone using Whatsapp. Unfortunately, webpages don't display well on smartphones unless they are optimized for the small screen... which usually means they have a mobile version.

Thus whenever I send a link, I always want to send a mobile friendly link. Usually prefixing `m.` before the URL brings up the mobile version, but sometimes it doesn't (Ex: http://500px.com/Jaanus)

I tried searching on Google, but could not find a resource which gives me the mobile version of a website/webpage (if a mobile version is available).

Any leads superusers?

Comment: Have you searched about User Agents? For Firefox, there's [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) addon. Essentially, by changing the User Agent to one similar to a mobile browser, you will access its mobile version.

Comment: My site doesn't have a separate mobile m. site but the site is optimized for mobile it auto detects the user agent and display the website in the format friendly for that user agent